# Can I say "He is down" in the following context: "He is down, in the ground floor"?

Tags: intransitive-preposition

I live on third floor in the hostel of the university, and sometimes friends ask me about other friend "where is he", and I know that he is on the ground floor. So my question is if I can say to them

> "He is down, in the ground floor",

or maybe it would be better to say

> "He is downstairs, in the ground floor".

The same question I have about "up" and upstairs.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can!

There are many ways to say this

> He's down there ***<del>in</del> on*** the ground floor

is one of them.

In the context of up/downstairs, you are right. You can use it that way. Check [OALD's](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/down_1) example

> *Mary's not down yet (= she is still upstairs).*

I'd suggest you to mention the place (or at least 'there') as well. Because just `he's down` [**also** means](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/down_4) he's dull/sad/depressed.

Answer (score 0):

At least in the AmE circles I run in, a building's floor is not well-localized (or perhaps it should be well-specified), so "on" rather than "in" is used, and I notice that you used this form ("I live on third floor") in your question. So you could easily say "He is down on the ground floor", or "He is downstairs, on the ground floor." Note also that you would not ordinarily use the comma in the first sentence, and it is optional in the second.

Specific parts of a floor are well-localized, so you could say "He's down in the lobby (on the first floor)."

And just to make things difficult, "basement" and "attic" are both considered appropriate for the use of "in": "He's down in the basement," "He's up in the attic."